# update string value at specific postion by 2

Tags: java

```
{
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        StringBuilder s = new StringBuilder ("1234S" );

        int t = s.charAt(4);

        t =t+2;

        s.setCharAt(3, 't');
    }

}
```

Comment: You seem to have forgotten to ask a question.

Comment: What is the problem? what do you expect?

Comment: i wish to update the value at nth position in string by 2

Answer (score 1):

First of all, `s.charAt(4)` would return the 'S' char, which I doubt you want to increment by two (unless you mean to change it to 'U').

Second of all, you should use a `char` variable.

And finally, I'm assuming you wish to modify the same index as the one you read from, and you probably want to modify it to the value of the `t` variable, not the character 't'.

```
StringBuilder s = new StringBuilder ("1234S");
char t = s.charAt(3);
t = (char)(t+2); // note that this will return a numeric character only if the original
                 // numeric character was between '0' and '7' 
s.setCharAt(3, t);
```

Comment: thanks Eran but i wish to update charAt 3 which is integer, would you be able to help in that.

Comment: @sankalpphirke I believe I just did.

Comment: yes, the only thing is, i  want int value to update and the setCharAt throws error if not casted, let me know if the error should not come.

Answer (score 0):

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    StringBuilder s = new StringBuilder ("1234S" );

    int t = s.charAt(3);

    t =(int) t+2;

    s.setCharAt(3, (char) t);

    System.out.println(s);
}
```

}
this worked out for me. Thanks

Comment: Accept [Eran answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/43845539/4391450), his code is cleaner with less unncessary casting.